# Fill NaN with 0 not apply on Dataframe while reading CSV

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I had applied `df.fillna(0)` to Datafarm `df` read from `CSV` file to fillout `NaN` with 0 but it not works
here is my code for reading and apply `fillna` method.

I have checked [here](http://%20https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) on Pandas website and all was same. Also some similar question on Stackoverflow like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13295735/how-can-i-replace-all-the-nan-values-with-zeros-in-a-column-of-a-pandas-datafram) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42363235/fill-nan-with-repeated-values). all checked not helped

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv(path to CSV file, header=None)
df.fillna(0)
print(df)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

only change `df.fillna(0, inplace = True)`

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv(path to CSV file, header=None)
df.fillna(0, inplace = True)
print(df)
```

Comment: the alternative without `inplace=True` would be to reassign df. `df = df.fillna(0)`